# multiple foreign keys to same table

Tags: mysql, join, foreign-keys

in one of my tables I had many fields which their value was on of these:

no, yes, yes (in front), yes (in rear), yes (in top) , yes (front and rear),  ....

so for yes it have a position too. I had two choices, first: add another position field for each column, second: create another table for storing these values and reference to that table. and I choose the second implementation.

but for retrieving data I have to join to the same table for many times (7 times) and I have to do about 15 other joins to retrieve other fields too (like brand name).
if my parent table have just ten thousand records and the reference table just have 10 or 11 records for retrieving data which method is better form performance perspective?

1- create a function in my application and get the value by providing the reference ID

2- use joins and renaming reference table in each join

if you have experienced same issue I will be appropriated to share it with me.

thank you in advance.

Comment: Joins are relatively expensive, and 15 is already quite a lot.  I am inclined to wonder whether you have normalized your schema past the point of usefulness.  In any case, performance questions are best approached by experimentation.  Use the `EXPLAIN` command to help you determine how your database structure affects performance for the queries you want to make.

Comment: MySql allows up to 61 table joins so there are scenarios which needed do too many joins. about my table it have more than 170 fields so having 15 foreign keys in it is not so weird ;)

Comment: The number of FKs in your table is not necessarily the issue.  The fact that a table is related to one or more others does not necessarily mean that you need to join all the related tables to correctly service every query.  Join only the ones you actually need in any particular query, and if that still means a large number of joins then consider denormalizing your data.

Comment: In particular, for standardized labels, consider offloading the label ID -> label text conversion to your display code instead of making the DB perform joins.  Load the reference table into a map, and have a display function that uses the map to display the appropriate label for each ID.  (So that's your option #1.)  This works best if your reference data are stable outside of application maintenance windows.